# My Plugin takes a long time at calculating requirements when installing

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I've developed an eclipse plugin and I have created an update site. 
The only problem I seem to be having is that it takes a long time when calculating requirements during the install process. Other plugins don't. Any Idea why it is like this?